# How to open a new window using a variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a complex jquery expression which I have stored in the variable "that":

```
that = $('table[class=a]').find('a[href^="xx"]').closest('td')[0]


<td>
    <a href="xx....">
</td>
```

I'm not sure how to open the contained link using "that" as the starting point. I tried

```
 $(that>'a').each(function(){
            window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
       });
```

this yields an empty set in firebug. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why don't you just stop here: `$('table[class=a]').find('a[href^="xx"]')`

Comment: I think it should be as simple as `that = $('table[class=a]').find('a[href^="xx"]'); window.location = that.prop('href')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to find the first enclosing `<td>`, you can simply shorten the expression to get only the anchors:

```
$('table.a a[href^="xx"]').each(function() {
    location.href = this.href;
    return false;
});
```

This will take the first anchor, and if it exists, change the location.